# Daemontools to run a python script

Tags: scripting, python, daemontools

I have a run sript under ress directory:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec python gmail_new15.py
```

And when I try to execute svc I get:

```
~# svc -du ress/
svc: warning: unable to control ress/: file does not exist
```

My goal is to control if the python script crashes and restart it.

```
~# ls ress/
run

~# cat ress/run 
#!/bin/sh

exec python gmail_new15.py
```

Comment: Gonna need more to go on than that.. Give me a ls -alh of the directory containing "ress" and the "ress" directory itself.

Comment: I've edited the question @TomO'Connor thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you started supervise ? The documentation for [svc](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/svc.html) states fairly explicitly that it "controls services monitored by supervise".

And looking at svc.c, that particular error message is raised when it cannot find/open the file supervise/control, wich is automatically created (along with the supervise directory) by supervise if it cannot find it.

See documentation [supervise](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/supervise.html) or [svscan](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/svscan.html) if you want to start supervise around more than one service.